# How to open RoomPlan data on devices without a LiDAR Scanner

Tags: core-data, ios-simulator, lidar, roomplan

I've saved my `RoomPlan.CapturedRoom` in `CoreData` as a `Data` object. When I open it again on a device WITH a LiDAR Scanner, it works totally fine. However, when I try to open it on the simulator for example, I get an error saying **"RoomPlan.CapturedRoom.Error.deviceNotSupported"**.

The code I use to convert the `Data` back to a `CapturedRoom` is this:

```swift
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            
do {
    self.capturedRoom = try decoder.decode(CapturedRoom.self, from: capturedRoomData)
} catch {
    let nserror = error as NSError
    fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
}
```

The fatalError is thrown here giving me the error above.

Comment: "deviceNotSupported" : I guess the simulator isn't supported. Avoid a `fatalErrror` if you don't want a crash. It's confirmed with https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/666947

Comment: I guess that's the case. A real device without a LiDAR Scanner is not supported either. This seems a bit dumb since I only want to view the data and not make a scan. Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: You can write your own class and map it to Apples CapturedRoom, and implement Codable. Another solution is to export the CapturedRoom to JSON.

Comment: Thanks! I actually ended up doing this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution posted by @Darkwonder is the right approach to this: "You can write your own class and map it to Apples CapturedRoom, and implement Codable. Another solution is to export the CapturedRoom to JSON."